# Running a statement for each transaction in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to set a PostgreSQL transaction timeout for each Spring transaction like so:

```
SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '10s';
```

How can I extend Spring to do that?

**I am not using Hiberante, but jOOQ, so setting a queryHint does not work in my case.**

Comment: As far is I know there is no Callback from Spring Transaction that could let you know that a transaction starts. So you have to set this variable in you code.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide your own extended transaction manager and add the behaviour in the appropriate spot, probably in the `begin` method.